# dropdown value is not getting selected ajax html() response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have written a dependable dropdown and its first get the id from the first dropdown and set the div id of the second drop down through ajax call. The issue is when I try to do with html() the second drop down first value can not be selected.

Here is the image of the dependable dropdown
[image]

Here is the code I am trying:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addNewFloor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="">
    <div class="modal-content">

    <?php echo form_open('registrations/saveNewFloor'); ?>

            <?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
                <CENTER><h3 style="color:green;">Data inserted successfully</h3></CENTER><br>
            <?php } ?>
      <div class="modal-header">
       <img src="assets/backend/img/floor.png" style="widows:50px;height:50px">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Register New Floor</h4>

      </div>
      <hr class="colorgraph">
       <div id="floorModelBox"></div>



      <div class="modal-body" style="margin-bottom:2px;padding-top:1px">


        <table class="table table-condensed" style="background-color:#F5F5F5;margin-bottom:1px">
        <caption><h3><small>Floor Path</small><h3></caption>
        <!------- Select Branch   --------------------->
        <tr><td>Select Branch</td><td >

        <select  class="form-control" name="branchId_floorModel1" id="branchId_floorModel" onChange="return selectBuildings_floorModel(this.value);selectBuildings_floorModel323();clearFloors();clearSections();clearIots();clearGateways();myFunction();" >                  
              <option value="0" selected> -- select Branch  --</option>              

               <?php 
              foreach($groups as $row)
            { 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->branchId.'">'.$row->branchName.'</option>';
            }
            ?>



              </select></td></tr>



              <tr><td>Select Building</td><td>


          <select  class="form-control" name="buildingBox_floorModel1"  style="width:100%;" id="buildingBox_floorModel" required>
              <option selected ="selected"  value="0">select Building</option></select>


                                       </td></tr>

              </table>



             <hr/>
             <table class="table table-condensed" style="margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:1px">
              <caption><h3><small>Floor Details </small><h3></caption>
              <tr><td>Floor Name :</td><td > <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="floorName_FloorModel" id="floorName_FloorModel" /></td></tr>
               <tr><td>Floor  No :  </td><td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  placeholder="building no" name="floorNo_FloorModel" id="floorNo_FloorModel" /></td></tr>




             </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-bottom:2px;padding-top:1px">
       <hr class="colorgraph">

               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " data-dismiss="modal"  onClick="window.location.reload();">CLOSE</button>

         <?php echo form_submit(array( 'class'=>'btn btn-success ', 'id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?><br/>
           <div id="fugo">

            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




function selectBuildings_floorModel(branchId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>registrations/get_building_section/' + branchId ,
        success: function (response)
        {
            jQuery('#buildingBox_floorModel').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

//controller method

```
  function get_building_section($branchId)
    {


    $this->MBuilding->get_building_by_branch($branchId);
      $sections = $this->db->get_where('building' , array(
          'branchId' => $branchId
       ))->result_array();

         // print_r($sections);die;
     foreach ($sections as $row) {

        //echo  $row['buildingName'];
           //
          echo '<option value="' . $row['buildingId'] . '">' . $row['buildingName'] . '</option>';
       }
   }
```

I even tried with the append() method, but then it's not clearing the dropdown list value.

Comment: except first other values are getting selected?

Comment: can you show us also method get_building_section?

Comment: yes except first value other values can selected

Comment: function get_building_section($branchId)
    {
     
     
    $this->MBuilding->get_building_by_branch($branchId);
      $sections = $this->db->get_where('building' , array(
          'branchId' => $branchId
       ))->result_array();
       
      // print_r($sections);die;
     foreach ($sections as $row) {
        
      //echo  $row['buildingName'];
           //
          echo '<option value="' . $row['buildingId'] . '">' . $row['buildingName'] . '</option>';
       }
   }

Comment: what do you mean by " but then it's not clearing the dropdown list value "?

Comment: when you select 1 value from first dropdown list and then you go to second drop down and coming back and select value from list 1  and then you go to second dropdown and the values are not getting cleared

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following...**

```
$("#branchId_floorModel").change(function (){
    // Your Code....
});
```